# How to prove the denseness of irrational lines in a torus by the Poincare recurrence theorem?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, dynamical-systems

We can prove that the irrational line $t\mapsto (\bar{t}, \bar{\alpha t})$ has dense image in the two dimensional torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$. But the prove I know is to reduce to $1$-dimensional case and prove by hand.

I have a feeling that we can prove this result by the Poincare Recurrence Theorem: If a flow preserves volume and has only bounded orbits, then for each open set there exist orbits that intersect the set infinitely often.

Do you know where I can find such a proof?